Is there a cross-platform way to determine if a device is powered via PSU or external battery in C?
I'm trying to wisely choose presentation modes for my Vulkan C program depending on the device and need a cross-platform script to determine if:

the device running the program is PC or Laptop/Phone
an uninterruptible PSU is present or the device is powered by internal battery

Both solutions are targeted to check for MAILBOX mode if battery is not present, otherwise check for RELAXED FIFO, so any of two solutions will fit my needs.
I know I can use macros to check if the device is Android or Apple with __ANDROID__ and __APPLE__, and also get battery status with WinAPI GetSystemPowerStatus(), but I don't wanna stick to some platforms writting application on Vulkan...
Is there a cross-platform way to check for presence of either Power Supply or Laptop/Phone battery?

Standard C does not have anything for this. If Vulkan itself doesn't expose this information, I think your only options are OS-specific code and a third party library that encapsulates the OS-specific code.

I have found a cross-platform way to do that with SDL_GetPowerInfo() in <SDL2/SDL_power.h> and check if output is SDL_POWERSTATE_NO_BATTERY (same is valid for SDL3 as well). Even tho libraries are off-topic there, it's open source, so you may go check the implementation on GitHub by yourself!

Yeah, I'm not surprised SDL has something for this.

I guess I'll upload an answer to my question then

There's a cross-platform way to check for battery status with SDL/SDL2/SDL3 with SDL_GetPowerInfo() in <SDL/SDL_power.h>. Then you can compare the status with SDL_PowerState enumerations, for instance:
SDL_PowerState systemPowerState = SDL_GetPowerInfo(NULL, NULL);
if (systemPowerState == SDL_POWERSTATE_NO_BATTERY)
    // check for mailbox
else
    // check for relaxed_fifo

